# Cannot run `invoke-sqlcmd` and cannot import SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to run `Invoke-Sqlcmd` on a computer and got the following error.

```
PS C:\> Invoke-Sqlcmd -server server1 'select 1 a'
Invoke-Sqlcmd : The 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' command was found in the module 'SqlServer', but the module could not be loaded.
For more information, run 'Import-Module SqlServer'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Sqlcmd -server server1 'select 1 a'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-Sqlcmd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
```

However, `Import-Module` failed?

```
PS C:\> Import-Module SqlServer
```

> Import-Module : The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Error in TypeData
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.Job": The member LastRunDuration is already present.
>   Error in TypeData "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.JobStep": The member LastRunDurationAsTimeSpan is already present.
>   Error in TypeData "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.NamedSmoObject": The member DefaultKeyPropertySet is already present.
>   Error in TypeData "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.NamedSmoObject": The member DefaultDisplayPropertySet is already present.
>   Error in TypeData "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.NamedSmoObject": The member DefaultDisplayProperty is already present.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Import-Module SqlServer
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-Module], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpdateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Comment: I installed sql server management studio 2017 on the computer

Comment: [It looks like this is a common issue if you have the previous SQLPS module installed](https://github.com/PowerShell/SqlServerDsc/issues/1097).  SQLPS came with pre-2016 (but post-2008) versions of sql server.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I don't know. I guess it comes with SSMS?

Comment: Try `import-module sqlps` and report back

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Found out `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` resolves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out that `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` resolved the problem.